# how to pass a String value to the following function

Tags: java, consumer

I have the following function with a consumer

```
Collection<String> abc;
@Override
public void something(Consumer<? super String> visitor) {

 abc.add(visitor);
}
```

I want to add values received to `something` function in the `abc` list. but I don't know how that will work?

In Main, I have the following code

```
String value = "usman"
   something(what should I write here to pass value and use in something)
```

Comment: Pass a string to what? `visitor`? If so, see [`Consumer#accept`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#accept-T-)

Comment: @user yes, my question is when I call `something` function what should I pass the value to it?

Comment: @Ahmed Ali Please describe your question and especially your problem better

Comment: That depends on what you want it to do. You're the one who wrote that code, not us. Anyways, the `something` method shouldn't work, because `abc` can only hold `String`s, not `Consumer`s

Comment: @Verity I have update the question

Comment: you want to convert the first code into the second code?

Comment: I want to pass the value to something function. but I cannot

Comment: Give it a consumer, something like `s -> System.out.println(s)`. But as I said before, what you give to the method depends on what *you* want to use it for. If you don't know what to pass to it, remove that method from your code. There's no point in keeping it around

Comment: @user I want to use the value passed to it to save in the array

Comment: I think you want `String visitor` instead of `Consumer<? super String> visitor` then

Comment: @user you understand what the idea is, but I cannot change the function signature.

Comment: You are showing by several aspects, that you don't understand the basics of Generics and maybe even of Collections. Please Google for some good tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your method `something` has argument `Consumer<? super String> visitor`, it means that you pass a function to the method `something` which accepts a String argument and returns nothing.

That is, you should be passing a function defined as a lambda expression:
`s -> abc.add(s)`

Such function *consumes* String value (yet to be provided) and adds it to some collection.

Thus, you should have a code like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;


public class MyClass {
    
    static Collection<String> abc = new ArrayList<>();
    
    static void something(Consumer<? super String> visitor) {
        String value = "usman"; 
        visitor.accept(value);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        
        something(s -> abc.add(s));
        
        System.out.println(abc);
    }
}
```

The output printed shows that the local value defined within `something` has been added to the collection:

```
[usman]
```

**Update**

If you need to use the value passed outside `something` method, you can just ignore the value passed to the Consumer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String mainValue = "mainValue";
    Supplier<String> supplier = () -> "supplier";

    something(s -> abc.add("literal"));
    something(s -> abc.add(mainValue));
    something(s -> abc.add(supplier.get()));

    System.out.println(abc);
}
```

Then only *outer* values are added to the collection:

```
[literal, mainValue, supplier]
```

Comment: I want the value you initialized inside the `something` method to come from main and then added to `abc` collection.